# Why are the 10 plagues in this specific order?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, yetziat-mitzrayim, plagues-makkos, bo, va-eira

Is there a specific reason for the sequence of the plagues? Why the plague of blood is followed by the plague of frogs, for example?

Comment: There's an interesting Zohar(?) that states it was corresponding to the steps HaShem took in creating the world in order to "recreate" the world with humanity as witnesses; if anyone wants to look for it and post, or your interest.

Answer (score 10):

Tanchuma Parshas Bo 4 explains the sequence (from Sefaria.org) by comparing the plagues to a siege upon an enemy City:

> נטה (את) ידך על השמים (שמות י כא). בטכסיס [מלך] בשר ודם הביא הקדוש ב"ה עליהם את המכות, מלך בשר ודם כיון שהמדינה מורדת עליו, מה עושה משלח לגיונות, והן מקיפין עליה, בתחילה הוא (שובר) [סוכר] אמת המים שלהם, אם חוזרין מוטב, ואם לאו הוא מביא עליהם קלנים, [ואם חוזרין מוטב, ואם לאו יורה בהן חצים, אם חוזרין מוטב, ואם לאו מביא עליהם, לגיונות, אם חוזרין מוטב, ואם לאו מביא עליהם דורמסיות], אם חוזרין מוטב, ואם לאו זורק בהם נפט, אם חוזרין מוטב, ואם לאו משליך בהם, אבני בליסטרא, ואם חוזרין מוטב, ואם לאו מגרה בהן (לגיונות ו) אוכלסין הרבה, אם חוזרין בהם מוטב, ואם לאו אוסר אותן בבית האסורין, אם חוזרין מוטב, ואם לאו הורג את הגדולים שבהם, כך הקב"ה בא על המצרים בטכסיס של מלכים, בתחילה (שבר) [סכר] אמת המים שלהן, שנאמר ויהפך לדן יאוריהם ונוזליהם בל ישתיון (תהלים עח מד), ולא חזרו הביא עליהם קלנים, אלו הצפרדעים, שנאמר על דבר הצפרדעים וגו' (שמות ח ח), ולא חזרו הביא עליהם את החצים, אלו הכנים, שנאמר ותהי הכנם [באדם ובבהמה] (שם שם יג), שהיתה נכנסת בגופו של מצרי כחץ הזה, [ולא חזרו הביא עליהן לגיונות זה ערוב שנאמר ישלח (בם) [בהם] ערוב ויאכלם (תהלים עח מה), ולא חזרו הביא עליהם דורמסיות, זה הדבר], ולא חזרו זרק בהן נפט זה השחין, ולא חזרו השליך בהן אבני בליסטרא, זה הברד, ולא חזרו ואחר כך, גירה בהן אוכלוסין הרבה, זה הארבה, ואחר כך נתנם בבית האסורים [זה החשך] שנאמר וימש חשך וגו' (שמות י כא), ולא חזרו והרג כל הגדולים שבהן, שנאמר וה' הכה כל בכור (שם יב כט).
>
> (Exod. 10:21:) STRETCH OUT YOUR HAND TOWARD THE HEAVENS. The Holy One brought the plagues upon them in the order of a flesh-and-blood [king]. In the case of a flesh-and-blood king, when a state revolts against him, what does he do? He sends out legions which surround it. First he {smashes} [dams up] their aqueduct. If they repent, well and good; but if not, he brings war cries against them. [If they repent, well and good; but if not, he shoots arrows at them. If they repent, well and good; but if not, he brings the legions against them. If they repent, well and good; but if not, he brings hand-to-hand combat against them.] If they repent, well and good; but if not, he hurls (boiling) naphtha at them. If they repent, well and good; but if not, he hurls stones at them from a catapult. Then, if they repent, well and good; but if not, he stirs up {six legions} a lot of troops against them. If they repent, well and good; but if not, he binds them in prison. If they repent, well and good; but if not, he kills their noble ones. So did the Holy One come against the Egyptians in the order of kings.
>   **1.** First he {smashed} [dammed up] their aqueduct(WATER SOURCE), as stated (in Ps. 78:44): HE TURNED THEIR NILES INTO BLOOD SO THAT THEIR STREAMS WERE UNDRINKABLE>.
>   **2.** When they did not repent, he brought war cries against them. These were the frogs, as stated (in Exod. 8:8): THEN MOSES CRIED OUT TO THE LORD> ABOUT THE MATTER OF THE FROGS….
>   **3.** Then, when they did not repent, he brought arrows upon them. These were the gnats, as stated (in Exod. 8:13 [17]): AND THERE WERE LICE [UPON HUMAN AND UPON BEAST], for each of them entered an Egyptian body like an arrow.
>   **4.** [Then, when they did not repent, he brought the legions upon them. These were (according to Rabbi Yehuda) Wild ferocious animals /(according to Rabbi Nechemia) swarms of flies, as stated (in Ps. 78:45): HE SENT - MIXTURES OF WILD ANIMALS / SWARMS OF INSECTS - AMONG THEM TO DEVOUR THEM.
>   **5.** Then, when they did not repent, he brought hand-to-hand combat upon them, as stated. This is the plague.]
>   **6.** Then, when they did not repent, he hurled naphtha at them. This corresponds to the boils.
>   **7.** Then, when they did not repent, he hurled great stones at them from a catapult. This is the hail.
>   **8.** Then when they did not repent even after that, he stirred up a lot of troops against them. These were the locusts.
>   **9.** Then after that he put them in prison. [This is the darkness,] as stated (in Exod. 10:21): DARKNESS THAT CAN BE TOUCHED….
>   **10.** Then, when they did not repent, he killed all their eldest sons, as stated (in Exod. 12:29): THAT THE LORD SMOTE ALL THE FIRST-BORN.